# Replace element in sorted range

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insert

There is an array `std::vector` of **unique** elements. It's sorted. It is known, that it contain an element with value `From`. I want to replace it with **unique** value `To` in optimal way keep tracking its *sorted* property. I can simply achieve it by means of `std::lower_bound`, then replace and finally apply `std::sort` to whole array, but I know - it is suboptimal, because there is only the subrange `[std::lower_bound(beg, end, From), std::upper_bound(beg, end, To))` should be reordered at maximum.

```
int From = 4;
int To = 7;
std::vector< int > v{2, 4, 6, 8};
auto const beg = std::begin(v);
auto const end = std::end(v);
*std::lower_bound(beg, end, From) = To;
std::sort(beg, end);
```

How to achieve desired using STL?

Comment: There is three cases: `if (From < To) {}`, `else if (To < from) {}` and `else {}`. But how to deal with `std::rotate(b,std::next(b),e)` correctly? Its preconditions are validity of ranges `[b,std::next(b))` and `[std::next(b),e)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the position of the element to replace, and find the position of where the element you are inserting should be, once it is inserted (use `lower_bound` for both these cases). Then replace the element, and rotate.

```
auto p1 = std::lower_bound(beg, end, From);
auto p2 = std::lower_bound(beg, end, To);
*p1 = To;
if (p1 < p2)
{
    std::rotate(p1, p1 + 1, p2);
}
else if (p2 < p1)
{
    std::rotate(p2, p1, p1 + 1);
}
```

Comment: Good, it works for single-element container. Thank you.

Comment: Is `(p1 < p2)` valid for non-random-access itarators?

Comment: I think it is better to use values of `From` and `To` themselves.

Comment: @Orient: No, it doesn't. You could of course check if `From < To`. But then, if you don't have random access iterators, you probably have what? A linked list? In which case, you probably want a completely different approach.

Comment: `std::lower_bound` and `std::rotate` require just a forward iterators.

Comment: @Orient: Yes, but you certainly wouldn't use them for this purpose on a linked list. You'd just do a linear search, and when you find the element to erase, remove it. And when you find the correct position for the new element, insert it.

Comment: I agree. The improvements are possible for another kinds of containers.

Answer (score 0):

[Slightly improved](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/889f363cd0d0e499) Benjamin Lindeley's solution:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

template< typename container, typename type >
std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of< std::random_access_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits< typename container::iterator >::iterator_category >::value >
replace(container & _container, typename container::value_type const & _from, type && _to)
{
    auto const beg = std::begin(_container);
    auto const end = std::end(_container);
    auto const from = std::lower_bound(beg, end, _from);
    auto const mid = std::next(from);
    if (_from < _to) {
        auto const to = std::lower_bound(from, end, _to);
        *from = std::forward< type >(_to);
        std::rotate(from, mid, to);
    } else if (_to < _from) {
        auto const to = std::lower_bound(beg, mid, _to);
        *from = std::forward< type >(_to);
        std::rotate(to, from, mid);
    } else {
        *from = std::forward< type >(_to);
    }
}

template< typename container, typename type >
std::enable_if_t< !std::is_base_of< std::random_access_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits< typename container::iterator >::iterator_category >::value
                  && std::is_base_of< std::forward_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits< typename container::iterator >::iterator_category >::value >
replace(container & _container, typename container::value_type const & _from, type && _to)
{
    auto const beg = std::begin(_container);
    auto const end = std::end(_container);
    if (_from < _to) {
        auto const from = std::lower_bound(beg, end, _from); 
        auto const to = std::lower_bound(std::next(from), end, _to);
        _container.insert(to, std::forward< type >(_to));
        _container.erase(from);
    } else if (_to < _from) {
        auto const to = std::upper_bound(beg, end, _to);
        auto const from = std::lower_bound(to, end, _from);
        _container.insert(to, std::forward< type >(_to));
        _container.erase(from);
    }
}

template< typename container >
bool
test(container lhs, int from, int to, container const & rhs)
{
    replace(lhs, from, to);
    return (lhs == rhs);
}

template< typename container >
bool
test()
{
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 1, {1, 4, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 2, {2, 4, 6, 8})) return false;//
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 3, {3, 4, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 5, {4, 5, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 7, {4, 6, 7, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 2, 9, {4, 6, 8, 9})) return false;

    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 1, {1, 2, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 3, {2, 3, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 4, {2, 4, 6, 8})) return false;//
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 5, {2, 5, 6, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 7, {2, 6, 7, 8})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 4, 9, {2, 6, 8, 9})) return false;

    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 1, {1, 2, 4, 6})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 3, {2, 3, 4, 6})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 5, {2, 4, 5, 6})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 7, {2, 4, 6, 7})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 8, {2, 4, 6, 8})) return false;//
    if (!test< container >({2, 4, 6, 8}, 8, 9, {2, 4, 6, 9})) return false;

    if (!test< container >({2}, 2, 2, {2})) return false;//
    if (!test< container >({2}, 2, 3, {3})) return false;
    if (!test< container >({2}, 2, 1, {1})) return false;
    return true;
}

int
main()
{
    assert((test< std::vector< int > >()));
    assert((test< std::deque< int > >()));
    assert((test< std::list< int > >()));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```